# why does this (int) cast not work with DateTime::format as expected?

Tags: php

```
   $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',"2038-01-20");
   $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',"2038-01-21");

    echo      ($date1->format("U")) . " " .      ($date2->format("U")) . "<br>";
    echo (int)($date1->format("U")) . " " . (int)($date2->format("U")); 
    exit;
```

This code outputs this

```
 2147570117 2147656517
 2147483647 2147483647 /*not correct*/
```

while It should outputs the same result whither I used `(int)` cast or not, as in

```
 2147570117 2147656517
 2147570117 2147656517 /*correct*/
```

why when I used `(int)` cast the values changed to be `2147483647` for both dates ?!

Comment: it exceeds int size limit

Comment: @PradyutManna ahaaaa, thank you very much.

Comment: You're using a 32 bit PHP. If you switch to a 64 bit it should support it just fine